# displaying data from database using model of codeigniter ,

Tags: codeigniter

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class MyModel extends CI_Controller {

    public function login_valid($username,$password)
    {
        $q=$this->db->where(['uname'=>$username,'pword'=>$password])->get('users');

        if($q->run_rows())
        {
            echo '<pre>';
            print_r($q->result() );
            exit;
            return $q=row()->id;
        }
        else
        {
            echo 'error';
        }
    }
}
```

When I call this using my controller,it shows nothing

Comment: Part of your code went hidden,I've edited for you.Accept the edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in Model use extends CI_Model (not CI_Controller)

```
class MyModel extends CI_Model
```